# Button with rounded bottom border

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm wondering if it is possible to create button looks like this:

[image]

With **CSS only** (no additional images).

What do you think?

Comment: Simply post the question on Google to found More Accurate Results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should post the code what tried so far. Any way try this one.

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
button {
  background: beige;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px maroon;
  border: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 0;
}
button:hover {
  background: #eaeab4;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #4d0000;
}
button:active {
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Text hover</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible using `box-shadow`. The example uses an anchor (`a`) tag but can very easily be adapted to a `button` also.

```css
a {
  background: beige;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px maroon;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px maroon;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px maroon;
}
```

```html
<a href='#'>Text hover</a>
```

---

**Applying on `button` element:** (Note to use `border: 0px` as buttons have a default border).

```css
.shape {
  background: beige;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px maroon;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px maroon;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px maroon;
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<button class='shape'>Text hover</button>
```

Comment: yes, or border : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ymg7dp5y/

Comment: @web-tiki: Yep mate. Border is also a good option (in fact more simpler for the shape in question) but as I indicated in the other answer's comment, I felt a `box-shadow` based example gives the OP more leverage if in future a separate border also needs to be added.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why everyone is suggesting to use `box-shadow`, you can do this with `border-radius` and a bottom border alone:

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

button {
  background: #B6B694; /* Guesswork, you can find the actual colour yourself. */
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f00;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<button>Text hover</button>
```

Comment: Very true, but suggested the box shadow just in case user wanted to add an actual border later on.

Comment: Don't forget to use 'outline: none;' to remove the 'border/outline' when you click on it.

Comment: @Nick OP hasn't specified that they *don't* want that to happen.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Some browsers give an outline when you click on it, it looks like a 1px dotter border but it isn't the border. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp

Comment: @Nick I'm well aware of that. But OP hasn't specified that this isn't desired.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/:

```
Example Q shows a shadow offset to the bottom and right by 5px, with a border-radius of 5px applied to each corner:
#Example_Q {
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px black;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px black;
box-shadow: 5px 5px black;
}

Example R shows the same shadow with a blur distance of 5px:
#Example_R {
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.example    {
    moz-border-radius:20px; 
    webkit-border-radius:20px;
    border-radius:20px;
}
```

You want to make sure the radius works in every browser so use this code make the radius to work in all browsers.

Comment: There's really no need to continue using the prefixed versions. The last version of Firefox which didn't support `border-radius` was version 3.6, for instance. Firefox is now on version 33. See: http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius.

Comment: But you still need `webkit-border-radius` for safari

Comment: Safari version 4, sure. Safari hasn't been updated on Windows in 4 years and even that is on version 5.1.

Comment: You also need `webkit` commands for Tizen, which is the operating system for Samsung

Comment: That uses Android Browser which has supported this since version 2.2 - and is now on version 4.4.

Comment: Here you see the newest Samsung being released with Tizen OS: http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_z-6403.php

Answer (score 0):

try it your own

```
border-radius:20px;

-moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
 box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
```